# Water comparison of different aqueous bodies in regions not affected by wildfire but adjacent to affected ones

Tags: water, wildfire, underground-water

Some big wildfires are hitting some places in Chile. I have read that aqueous bodies can be affected during/after major wildfires. Is it possible to determine if it is safe to drink spring water (flowing from rocks/roots of a tree/underground sources) just by observing the water and its surroundings, without examining the water to determine its composition ? (some signal where to put attention to the naked eye)

Compared to (for example, in the same region) water coming from other type of aqueous bodies (this, in regions not suffering with wildfires, but, adjacent to, and presenting some variation in weather due to smoke).